# Selenium - click on a toggle element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am struggeling with selenium.

Basically I want to click the following element to toggle the element:

```
<div class="view-icon fadeIn" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Switch to List View">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
```

It *changes* to:

```
<div class="view-icon fadeIn" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Switch to Tab View">
<i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
</div>
```

After that I just want to fill in the form and test its output.

The method I wrote for clicking this element:

```
public void clickAtListView() {
        WebElement listView = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='view-icon fadeIn']"));
        listView.click();
    }
```

However, i am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 50 milliseconds
```

Any recommendations why I get this exception?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

It seems to me that the list element gets shown when I put `Thread.sleep(10000);` before:

However, i still get the exception ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your sent exception said the element is not visible to take any action.

Hence, your code

```
WebElement listView = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='view-icon fadeIn']"));
```

gets a hidden element (E.g. "View Tab" element). Please try this one

```
WebElement listView = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-original-title='Switch to List View']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to add one extra path to your XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/[@class='view-icon fadeIn']/i"));
```

Additionally, instead of defining separate elements for Tab View and List View, you can use the selector above as, for example, Toggle Views.