# Selenium - Setting toggle

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am attempting to automate tests on my company's product. They use a sort of a toggle. I have the HTML and an image of the toggle below. I've found a seeming answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682401/901083, yielding XPath code of `//div[@class='toggle btn btn-default off btn-sm']`, but that div changes to "toggle btn btn-sm btn-primary" once clicked and "toggle btn btn-sm btn-default off" again when it comes back. How do I generically refer to that div no matter its setting?

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 80px; height: 30px;" class="toggle btn btn-default off btn-sm" data-toggle="toggle">
    <input data-off="O" data-on="I" data-size="small" data-toggle="toggle" data-val="true" data-val-required="The OptInReceiveEmail field is required." 
        data-width="80px" id="OptInReceiveEmail" name="OptInReceiveEmail" tabindex="0" value="true" type="checkbox">
    <div class="toggle-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm toggle-on">I</label><label class="btn btn-default btn-sm active toggle-off">O</label>
        <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default btn-sm"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: Sorry. I got moved over to another section of the project and didn't get a chance to try out the solution. I'll go at it again when I get to work on Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there no other toggle buttons on the page, you can, for example, check for the presence of `data-toggle` attribute:

```
//div[@data-toggle]
```

If there are other toggle buttons and you need this particular "Email" toggle:

```
//div[@data-toggle][input/@id = "OptInReceiveEmail"]
```

Comment: That works. For some reason, I thought that targeting the Div wasn't allowing for the click. I must have confused a different error.